# Git : produce clean repo by relocating big files

Tags: git, version-control, shared-libraries

Ahhh I remember those days when I was a git newbie and I commited all those big library files along with my projects...

But now I'm trying to ressurect an old project like this, and I want to "purify" my repository stored on my school's server (and hell, it was hard to download those MB in one shot without the fetch failing in the middle !)

By "purify", I mean that I'd like to make an other repository from the existing one, if possible maintaining the "commits/branch" structure, but getting rid of some files/folders of my choosing.

In details, let's say I have this big folder `/lib/` along with eventually some other ones, that I want to totally separate. But if possible, I'd like to have a clean, reversible separation : in every commit, I should keep some hash or whatever may give me a hint as to what the content of the `/lib` folder was.

The ideal solution would be to have two repositories that are always synchronized and with the "same commits"

- One repository with just the code, without the `/lib folder`
- One repository, with the same "commit references", but where the content of the commits are only the contents of the `/lib/` folder

In other words, what I'm trying to do is recreate artificially some kind of dependency manager (If only I had started a maven or so straight from the start.. sigh)

**In a nutshell** two steps :

- Getting rid of a lib folder in every commits
- Inserting in the commits who have lost `/lib` deltas, some info or pointer  where I can find information on the files that were previously there (or maybe a link to another commit of a repo who would only contain the evlution of the `/lib` folder ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should apply [interactive rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_splitting_commits) approach.

You can mark commits that contain some library code with `edit` tag. While rebasing you will be able to drop that libarary code and change commit message to point your original commit code.

Comment: Hmm interesting ! I'd still have to do most of the work by hand, but I guess it's unavoidable.